# Add Foreign Key in SQL by My-SQL Workbench gives Error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I want to add a Foreign Key to a table called "address".

```
ALTER TABLE `students1`.`address` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `id_country`
FOREIGN KEY ()
REFERENCES `students1`.`country` ()
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

This request was automatically generated by MySQLWorkbench.
But get this error

```
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
REFERENCES `students1`.`country` ()
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACT' at line 3
```

How fix this?

Comment: This is just invalid SQL. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to add a foreign key to another already existing table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know if your **both** tables have the same column `id_country`.

But the syntax in that case is:

```
ALTER TABLE `students1`.`address` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT 
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_country`)
    REFERENCES `students1`.`country`(`id_country`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```